# Named PIPE (FIFO) reading content of file in C

Tags: c, pipe, named-pipes, fifo

Basically I want my client program to read data from a file (file name/path specified in the command line input) and copy that data to the FIFO and I want my server program to read from the FIFO and print every line.

For example if I want to print the contents of the /etc/passwd text file I run the program in the terminal in this way:

```
./server &
./client < /etc/passwd
```

However, instead of printing any output, it prints out nothing but 'done'.
Why?
Here's my code:
server.c

```
//server.c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define FIFONAME "myfifo"

int main(void){

    int n,fd;
    char buffer[1024];
    unlink(FIFONAME);

    //create FIFO

    if(mkfifo(FIFONAME,0666)<0){
        perror("server: mkfifo");
        exit(1);
    }
    //open FIFO for reading
    if((fd = open(FIFONAME, O_RDONLY))<0){
        perror("server: open");
        exit(1);
    }
    //READ from fifo UNTIL end of tile and print 
    //what we get on the standard input
    while((n=read(fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer)))>0){
        write(1, buffer, n);
    }

    close(fd);
    exit(0);
}
```

.
client.c

```
//client.c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FIFONAME "myfifo"

int main(void){

    int n,fd;
    char buffer[1024];

    /* open, read, and display the message from the FIFO */
    if((fd = open(FIFONAME, O_WRONLY))<0){
        perror("client: open");
        exit(1);
    }
    //read from standard input and copy data to the FIFO
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0){
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
        write(fd, buffer, n);
    }


    close(fd);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: are you sure that the server has the time to create the FIFO before the client starts (that would create a regular file on the client side)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre indeed it does have enough time to create FIFO before the client begins!

Comment: can you add a `sleep` between server & client? doesn't cost much, but worth a try.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre added sleep but its not working. Maybe I placed it in the wrong place?

Answer (score 2):

this code is wrong:

```
 while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0){
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
        write(fd, buffer, n);
```

this loops consumes the input, then reads it again. You're losing the first (and possibly the only) `buffer`. I would do (maybe not the best code but works):

```
 while (1){
        if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)==0) break;
        write(fd, buffer, n);
 }
```

Aside, as noted in my comments, running the server in background to create the FIFO and running the client without waiting for the FIFO to be created is a potential race condition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I added a sleep of 2 seconds in the client program in the beginning as you suggested but it still prints out 'done' and no output of the text file.  
`
 int n,fd;   
    char buffer[1024];   
   
    /* open, read, and display the message from the FIFO */      
    sleep(2);   ` //added the sleep here in the client file

Comment: yeah, but did you read my answer fully? your client code is _wrong_

Comment: yes it's wrong and hence I've changed my client code to the one you suggested to in my text editor.

Comment: Unfortunately, no it isn't :(

Comment: 1) have you tried to print what you're reading from the client side 2) what is this "done" output? probably the server exiting.

Comment: i tried printing from client side too but not working